# What codes are copied to the child process?

Tags: process, c

If we call the method fork() inside an if statement, does the generated child process enter into the else statement ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void){
    int c = rand() % 50;

    if( c == 0 ){
        int k = fork();
    }
    else{
        printf("ELSE");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After the fork() is executed, does the child process print "ELSE" message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The child process will find itself at exactly the same point in the code as the parent at the time of the `fork()`. The only difference in the state of parent and child is the return value from the `fork()` call, assigned to `k` in your code (this will hold the PID of the child in the parent process, and it will be zero in the child process). If the `fork()` happens, neither parent nor child will reach the `printf()` statement.

The usual way to do a `fork()` is

```
pid_t pid;

pid = fork()

if (pid == 0) {
    /* child process code */
    /* including exit()   */
} else {
    /* parent process code           */
    /* including waitpid() or wait() */
}
```

Comment: `int c; int k;` I think that these two statements are copied to child process.

Comment: @Goktug Yes, as I wrote in [my answer to your question yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427938/116858), all code is copied to the child. The child process is an _exact_ copy of the parent process. However, the child will start executing _after the `fork()`_ (it will have the same values for all variables as the parent had at that point, except for the value of `k` which will be zero).

Comment: I am sorry, but my university professor only says that fork() is special function and returns two different values. I have to do research about the mechanism of the fork(). I might ask similar questions about the fork(). Thank you for your all explanations.

Comment: @Goktug Your professor is correct. If it is successful, the fork function returns two values. One value is returned to the parent (this is the PID of the child), and the other value is returned to the new child process (this value will be zero).